# what is an alternative to irfan view- sharpen feature?

Tags: 16.04

I have around 250 pictures containing text which I have to study. The problem is the pictures are blurry. So as I go through the pictures using irfan view in windows, i just press "shift+S"- easy shortcut to instantly make your picture sharp and readable.
Apparantly irfan doesnot run even with wine 1.9. 
I found feh with easy sharp feature with combination of Ctrl+right drag

Is there any alternative so that I can do above without involving the mouse like I do with irfan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use command line you can use `convert` which is a part of `imagemagic` package installed by default in `16.04`. For all eg. jpg files in directory you can use simple for loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.jpg; do
   convert -sharpen 0x3 "$i" new_"$i"
done
```

It will create new converted files in directory where you are. Sharpen `0x3` is quite strong you can try `0x2` at first -> [here is a description](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#sharpen).

---

You can also use [xnview](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads) as an alternative to iview

Answer (score 1):

No alternative required as on my Xenial system using the Repository Wine:

```
andrew@athens:~$ wine --version
wine-1.6.2
```

and the latest 64bit IrfanView there was absolutely no issues running this application. I note as well there are glowing reports (if not somewhat old ones) [on WineHQ...](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=7834)

Screenshot on my system, and yes the 'Sharpen' command works fine:

[image]